# Finding the sum of even valued terms in fibonacci sequence using for loop

Tags: python

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

```
prev, cur = 0, 1
total = 0
while True:
    prev, cur = cur, prev + cur
    if cur >= 4000000:
        break
    if cur % 2 == 0:
        total += cur
print(total)
```

How can i solve this using for loop?

Comment: So... what's the problem with this code? BTW "do not exceed" means "less than or equal to", so the break condition should be `cur > 4000000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first = 0
second = 1
for i in range(1,4000000):
    next=(first+second)
    print(next)
    first=second
    second=next
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci sequence reaches 4000000 from the 34th element

```
prev, cur = 0, 1
total = 0
for i in range(34):
    prev, cur = cur, prev + cur
    if cur % 2 == 0:
        total += cur
print(total)
```